# Does anyone know how to register for Google Backup API key now?

Tags: android, backup, api-key

The URL to register for Google Backup API key no longer works.

(http://code.google.com/android/backup/signup.html) - I am redirected to my developer console.

Does anyone know how to register an app for a new API key now?

Comment: You should edit your question. It is unclear that you have problems with retrieving your API key. The question asks for the new URL, but that's not your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now at https://developers.google.com/android/backup/signup

found in these docs:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#BackupKey

What's strange, is that http://code.google.com/android/backup/signup.html should be redirecting you to the https://developers.google.com/android/backup/signup page anyway. I'm not sure how you are having a problem with that.

**EDIT:** Based on your comments, a bug have been reported: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26936

FYI: I'm having the same issue, hopefully it works tomorrow (it seems to have been a problem before and then fixed shortly thereafter). Worth commenting on the bug, if that's not you who did already.

Comment: Well, the docs seem to be wrong. I am just redirected to my developer console after I enter my package name and click register.

Comment: So your problem is not with the new URL, but the actual retrieval of an API key is not being offered after you check agree to the ToS and click Register. That's a different problem than 'where is the new URL'

Comment: Thank you. Hoping for a fix soon.

Comment: someone probably forgot to update the backup service from the market to google play... same thing happens here.

Comment: It's working now, for me at least. They have a new redirect message at the top if coming from code.google instead of developers.google and it now brings you to correct http://play.google.com/apps/publish/GetBackupApiKey?p=com.company.appname respectively after pressing submit. So, it looks to be resolved! Hurray